# Set option selected attribute from sql return value

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have this function that is supposed to echo the full option values that is returned from the while loop. The problem is that the SELECT attribute is not being set. So the list options default to the first option even when a different id variable is passed.

```
function popselect($pos){
$pquery = "SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `position` = '$pos'";
$presult = mysql_query($pquery)
    or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error());


$tquery = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE `selection_id` = '$id'";
$tresult = mysql_query($tquery)
or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
$trow = mysql_fetch_array($tresult);


    while (($prow = mysql_fetch_array($presult)) != null){

        $fullname = $prow['name'].' '.$prow['surname'];
        $selected = "";

        if ($fullname == $trow['f']){
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';}
        if ($fullname == $trow['gk']){
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';}
        if ($fullname == $trow['ld']){
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';}
        if ($fullname == $trow['rd']){
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';}
        if ($fullname == $trow['lm']){
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';}
        if ($fullname == $trow['rm']){
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';}

        echo "<option value='{$fullname}' ".$selected.">".$fullname."</option>";

        }
}
```

The html is as follows:

```
<fieldset>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <div id="l"><label for="gk">Goalkeeper:</label></div>
                    <div id="s"><select name="gk">
                        <?php popselect(Goalkeeper)?>
                    </select></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="l"><label for="f">Forward:</label></div>
                    <div id="s"><select name="f">
                        <?php popselect(Forward); ?>
                    </select></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="l"><label for="lm">Left Midfielder:</label></div>
                    <div id="s"><select name="lm">
                        <?php popselect("Left Midfielder"); ?>
                    </select></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="l"><label for="rm">Right Midfielder:</label></div>
                    <div id="s"><select name="rm">
                        <?php popselect("Right Midfielder"); ?>
                    </select></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="l"><label for="ld">Left Defender:</label></div>
                    <div id="s"><select name="ld">
                        <?php popselect("Left Defender"); ?>
                    </select></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="l"><label for="rd">Right Defender:</label></div>
                    <div id="s"><select name="rd">
                        <?php popselect("Right Defender"); ?>
                    </select></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Where does `$id` come from in your query for `$trow`? My guess is that `$id` is empty at that point, query selects nothing and `$trow` is therefore empty too.

Comment: Have you checked the content of `$prow`? Of `$trow`? What's in your tables? Have you even tried to debug your code?

Comment: The $id variable is from $_GET['id'] that is sent from the referrer page...

Comment: Yes randomSeed, i spent hours trying to figure it out.... those array values are definitely there...

Comment: If anybody can help I will gladly give you ftp access to the host server

Answer (score 0):

The problem was variable scope...

My function did not have access to $id...

```
$tquery = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE `selection_id` = '$_GET['selection_id']'";
```

worked a charm!